# DTX402k eDrum kick sounds opaque into PA SPEAKER

Tags: drums, speakers, electronic-drumset, pa

I was wondering if I need a mixer between my DTX402k and my BEHRINGER B112 PA speaker in order to get the sound of my kick pad right.
When I connect my headphones it sounds perfect but once I try to connect directly to my PA it sounds opaque hardly hear when I kick.

What am I doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried plugging headphone output to the speaker? I have a synth that sounds terrible through the designated line out and much better when I plug the headphone output to line input.

Comment: Is the DTX402k output stereo?  Is the B112 input stereo?  If you're taking only one channel, that may be the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

How loud is your PA speaker? The kick-drum sound is mainly low-end, and the volume from the speaker can easily be overpowered by the noise of the physical pedal. With headphones, this will be less of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, p.a.speakers have a wider sound spectrum than, say, guitar speakers. They need to be able to produce both high and low pitches equally. So your drumkit maybe isn't giving it enough boost at certain frequencies, and a mixer may be the answer. Except that you probably only have two channels - left and right - that you can plug into that p.a.amp/speaker, and that's made worse by the fact that all that is 'monoed' due to only using one speaker! Although there will be tone controls on that mixer. A graphic equaliser may help, as that can boost certain frequencies more accurately. But where it would go in the chain - you'll have to experiment. I'd say between brain and amp., but bear in mind the g.e. will influence any other sounds going into it.

Another thought - on my Yamaha and Alesis kit, each drum/cymbal has its own volume control, after getting into the menu a bit. Your, presumably Yamaha kit should also. Time to read instructions!